Disable hover-state externally
I have a context menu.
When I hover a node, it gets highlighted(like it should).
But when I enter the context menu, the node stays highlighted. I would like to disable the hover/highlighted state manually.
I have tried setting the node.hover/node.highlighted attribute and called sigma.refresh(), but that doesn't do it. The node stays highlighted.

Can you help me?
It only resets when I move my mouse from the context menu back into the stage area.
